# Getting error "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, nuget-package, .net-4.8

The error message you're encountering states:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

It seems like there's a version conflict with the Newtonsoft.Json library. Owin.* requires a version greater than 10.0.3, while Google.Apis.Core requires version 13.0.3. Currently, you have Newtonsoft.Json version 13.0.3 installed.

To resolve this, you might need to use binding redirects in your application configuration file (`web.config`) to force the use of a specific version of Newtonsoft.Json throughout your application. Here's how you can do it:

1. Open your `web.config` file.
2. Add the following configuration under the `<configuration>` element:

```xml
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.3.0" newVersion="13.0.3.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

This configuration tells the application to use Newtonsoft.Json version 13.0.3 whenever a version between 0.0.0.0 and 13.0.3.0 is requested.

After adding this configuration, rebuild your application and try running it again. This should resolve the assembly version conflict issue.

Comment: Well, did you try what was suggested by the chatbot?

Comment: Sorry I don't know this feature, can you guide me?